# How to split table using excerpt_separator in markdown in jekyll blog

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I use a table in a post, as the table is too long, so I want to add the `excerpt_separator` (say, `<!-- more -->`) to split the table: if the reader is interested in it, he can click `read more` to get the whole table. But I can't achieve this. My code as below:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |  
|----------|----------|----------|  
| Row 1    |          |          |  
| Row 2    |          |          |  
<!-- more -->
| Row n    |          |          |
```

So, the question is: how to split the table just using `excerpt_separator`?

Comment: [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) has no notion of an "`excerpt_separator`". Some other Markdown libraries add features (e.g. fenced code blocks or footnotes). Please add detail about which Markdown library you are using, and how you're using it (e.g. perhaps inside a Jekyll blog or a GitHub `README.md` file).

Comment: OK, I've done some modifications. In a word, the problem came out when I wrote a post of jekyll blog using a long table.